# Prove that for any integer $n > 3$ there exist positive integers $a_1 > \dots > a_n$ such that $1 = \frac{1}{a_1} + \dots + \frac{1}{a_n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers

I have tried to approach this problem in a variety of ways, like triyng to construct a solution, looking at telescoping series, geometrically... But I have been unable to solve it. I would appreciate any hint. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: $\frac{1}{d} = \frac{1}{d+1} + \frac{1}{d(d+1)}$. Look at wiki entry of [Stkvester's sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_sequence) for connection of this to Egyptian fraction representation of one.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_fraction

Comment: Thanks! I have solved it by induction now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since OP has solved the question, here is another solution to the question (besides using Sylvester's sequence). Observe for $n\ge3$:

$$1 - \frac1{2^{n-2}}=\frac12+\frac14+\dots+\frac1{2^{n-2}}$$

and

$$\frac1{2^{n-2}} = \frac 1{3 \times 2^{n-1}}+\frac1{3\times 2^{n-2}}$$

and thus

$$1 = \frac12+\frac14+\dots+\frac1{2^{n-2}}+\frac 1{3 \times 2^{n-1}}+\frac1{3\times 2^{n-2}}$$

which consists of exactly $n$ terms.